# Multiple ascending order is not working in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have one table called as `request` and there are three columns called as `Id, want, teach`. I have to display `want` and `teach` column in ascending order and I don't want to display NULL and blank rows.

I tried query only `want` column is displaying in ascending order but `teach` column is not displaying in ascending.

```
  SELECT want, teach FROM request WHERE want IS NOT NULL OR want !='' AND teach IS NOT NULL OR teach !='' GROUP BY want, teach ORDER BY want ASC, teach ASC
```

If I write ORDER BY teach ASC, want ASC then teach column is displaying in Ascending order and want is showing DESC order.
Would you help me in this?

Chech left side column is want and right side column is teach. I am getting output like this. left side column is ASC order but right side is showing DESC
[image]

Comment: The result of the query (the ordering of data) will depend very much on the existing data in the table. Will you provide some sample data ,expected result for that data and what you are currently getting?

Comment: Mr.Muntasir, I updated my description. Please check.

Comment: @NarendraVerma do you understand my ans ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to understand order by

if you give 1st,2nd asc order it will frist asc the 1st column and depend on this it will asc 2nd column.
for example

```
1st  2nd               
1    b
2    d
3    a
2    a
1    a
```

order by convert in

```
 1st   2nd 
  1     a
  1     b
  2     a
  2     d
  3     a
```

So you need to different query

```
     SELECT want FROM request WHERE want IS NOT NULL OR want !='' GROUP BY 
 want ORDER BY want ASC

     SELECT teach FROM request WHERE teach IS NOT NULL OR teach !='' GROUP
 BY  teach ORDER BY teach ASC
```

Comment: Yes, Mr.knowledge, We can use only two multiple queries,..Working for me

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the point of multi order here.

firstly , by default, most of dbms sorting as `ASC`.

Multiple ordering depending on the order of sorted columns, which is mean that -so to speak- :-

*" hey sql ! select some result from my table , order them by col1 and group them by this order , then this sorted or grouped data set , sort them by col2. "*

it's kind of multidimensional sorting so to speak.

take this as an example :

```
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
|  id  |   want  | teach |                   |  id  |   want  | teach |
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
|   1  |    1    |   2   |    ORDER BY       |   2  |    1    |   1   |
|   2  |    1    |   1   |       want asc,   |   1  |    1    |   2   |
|   3  |    2    |   1   |       teach asc   |   4  |    1    |   2   |
|   4  |    1    |   2   |                   |   3  |    2    |   1   |
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
```

and when you revert the order of sorted columns like this :

```
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
|  id  |   want  | teach |                   |  id  |   want  | teach |
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
|   1  |    1    |   2   |    ORDER BY       |   2  |    1    |   1   |
|   2  |    1    |   1   |       teach asc,  |   3  |    2    |   1   |
|   3  |    2    |   1   |       want asc    |   1  |    1    |   2   |
|   4  |    1    |   2   |                   |   4  |    1    |   2   |
+------+---------+-------+                   +------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Hassan Ahmed, exactly same thing happened to me then How can I display both columns IN ASC order?

Comment: using php or it's alternatives to sort it maybe be a good work around, if you are uses php. if you want a pure sql solution , so either make a two separates queries or use sub query or unions to work around it .