# MySQL sorting based on two columns

Tags: java, mysql

I have a sql query which results in the following table.

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| tp_id | tp_title | tp_completed_at     | uto_order                            |
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 69033 | task3    | 2017-03-17 08:15:38 | 3401893506280706400000000.0000000000 |
| 69022 | post 1   | 2017-03-15 10:24:03 | 1122274146401882300000000.0000000000 |
| 69032 | task4    | 2017-03-17 08:15:35 |  810531327956915000000000.0000000000 |
| 68998 | final    | 2017-03-13 14:23:18 |  498788509511947700000000.0000000000 |
| 68978 | app4     | 2017-03-13 14:05:39 |  221683782005310100000000.0000000000 |
| 68850 | 7        | 2017-02-24 07:58:38 |   12974633789062503000000.0000000000 |
| 68845 | 6        | 2017-02-24 07:54:14 |    5766503906250001000000.0000000000 |
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to sort the result based on `tp_completed_at` and `uto_order` independently. I mean, first the query should sort the result based on `tp_completed_at` and then again it should sort the entire data based on `uto_order` for records having just same date in `tp_completed_at` (excluding timestamp), For eg, task 3 and task 4 would be next to each other after sorting based on `tp_completed_at` as shown below

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| tp_id | tp_title | tp_completed_at     | uto_order                            |
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 68845 | 6        | 2017-02-24 07:54:14 |    5766503906250001000000.0000000000 |
| 68850 | 7        | 2017-02-24 07:58:38 |   12974633789062503000000.0000000000 |
| 68978 | app4     | 2017-03-13 14:05:39 |  221683782005310100000000.0000000000 |
| 68998 | final    | 2017-03-13 14:23:18 |  498788509511947700000000.0000000000 |
| 69022 | post 1   | 2017-03-15 10:24:03 | 1122274146401882300000000.0000000000 |
| 69032 | task4    | 2017-03-17 08:15:35 |  810531327956915000000000.0000000000 |
| 69033 | task3    | 2017-03-17 08:15:38 | 3401893506280706400000000.0000000000 |
+-------+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

and again I want to sort (6 and 7) based on uto_order, (app4 and final) based on `uto_order`,(task4 and task 3) based on `uto_order` since all this group of tasks have `tp_completed_at` as the same day . How to do it? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you mean `sort` by `tp_completed_at` first and sort by `uto_order` if two records have same value for `tp_completed_at`?

Comment: Like you explain, if you sort a set twice independently, this only will be sorted based on the last sort. But if what you really want is to sort based on `tp_completed_at` and then, for every similar value, sort those blocs based on `uto_order`, simply `ORDER BY tp_completed_at, uto_order`. Please edit the question with the expected output with a good example.

Comment: may be this ans will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719808/2286537

Comment: So first, you want to order by datetime but then, for every same date, order on the second column. Or is it OK to order on date the `tp_completed_at` ?

Comment: @Darshan Mehta....yes but, I should only consider yyyy-mm-dd part of the tp_completed_at i.e when, the "yyyy-mm-dd" part of the tp_completed_at is same, then it should sort based on uto_order

Comment: @SandeshaJ thanks, I have added an answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ORDER BY CAST(tp_completed_at AS DATE) DESC, uto_order
```

Comment: I should consider same date event. I should not consider timestamp value in the field tp_completed_at

Comment: Then maybe try: ORDER BY CAST(tp_completed_at AS DATE) DESC, uto_order

Comment: Sorting in an ORDER BY is done by the first column, and then by each additional column in the specified statement.
In other words, the data is first sorted in Column1 order, and then each subset (Column1 rows that have 2017-03-17 as their value) are sorted in order of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort on `date` part of `tp_completed_at` and then by `uto_order` then you can use MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT` function, e.g.:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(tp_completed_at, '%Y-%m-%d'), uto_order;
```

Comment: I think this will only be part correct. The idea is to order the `tp_completed_at` on the data provided but on the second order (`uto_order`) order them for the same `tp_completed_at` date. I don't see any way to do this kind of conditionnal order.