# select distinct and order by multiple smallint columns

Tags: php, mysql

Columns `width` and `height` are `smallint(6)`.
I want to select `distinct` values from `width` order by `width asc` and then order by `height asc`.
Here is my try:

```
- $sql = "select * from banners group by width order by width, height asc";  
- $sql = "select * from banners group by width order by width asc, height asc";  
- $sql = "select * from banners group by width order by width asc, height";
```

Nothing works. Selection is ordered fine by width, but not properly by height.

Comment: can you show some sample data ?

Comment: and expected output please

Comment: may this ans help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719808/2286537

Comment: Why `group by width`?

Comment: @Forward, because I need only distinct values from `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of group by instead of distinct is no proper  (and starting form  mysql 5.7 is not allowed ) for  select only one row without explicit name

You should use explicit column name in select and  aggregation function for column name not in group by

in this way you really control the selected value and the order of the resultin rows

eg:

```
select distinct width,  height 
from banners 
order by width, height asc
```

or

```
select  width,  max(height )
from banners 
group by width
order by width, height asc
```